# Receiving a gradle build error while trying to run application on Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, gradle, visual-studio-code, build

When attempting to run my application I am receiving two errors, the first error

1.

```
Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0-rc-1-bin.zip'.
Supplied javaHome must be a valid directory. You supplied: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17
```

The second is telling me that my "main" method could not be found in my application. My source code is all good, because my friend was able to run  the exact same source code on his machine.

However, I noticed that when he ran the application a .gradle folder was automatically created, but for me no such folder is created

**My friends files structure**

[image]

**My File Structure**

I have attached my file structure and his file structure below, as well as my build.gradle file.

[image]

I noticed that the .gradle file does not exist for my project, but does for his project(which  is the same untouched source code)

This is my build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.8'
    implementation 'com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.9.3'
    implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '1.7.+'
    implementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.0'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.0'
}
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(11)
    }
}
version = '1.2.1'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/main'
       }
   }
   test {
       java {
           srcDir 'src/test'
       }
   }
}
mainClassName = 'uni.App'
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Does the `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17` directory exist on your system? If it exists, what does it contain

Comment: It is simply a installation of Java.

Answer (score 1):

JDK 17 hasn't been supported yet. There is [an experimental developer build](https://mobile.twitter.com/fbricon/status/1440618003825971202) to try though, not sure if you're already using that.

Regarding to the folder `.gradle`, it is Project-specific cache directory generated by Gradle. See [Project Root Directory](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/directory_layout.html#dir:project_root). You may install other supportable jdk then with the extension [Spring Initializr Java Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-spring-initializr), try creating Gradle Project again.